# How to Find invoking Portlet by URL in Liferay Portlet 4.2.2

Tags: url, portlet

I need to find the portlet which is invoking by below URL.

> /web/guest/departments/bc/forms/wsp

We are using Liferay Portlet 4.2.2 version

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for the above question.

The link provide above is Friendly URL. Login as Administrator, go to page settings. you can find the invoking portlet for that page.